# Find element in array of HTML element with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

After a click on my element i can display the path :

```
console.log(e.path)
```

This gave me an array :

```
[i.fi.fi-bubble, button.c-block, div, body.u-help, html, document, Window]
```

I want to find in this array if there is an element with class "c-block" with pure Javascript

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: array.includes("c-block")

Comment: You won’t get such a path in your actual code, that is just something logging to console does. Simply go from the element to the parent, and check if it has that class. If not, keep going up until you find one with that class, or there is not more parent.

Comment: @rahulmr That won't work - it's not an array of strings, plus it's `button.c-block`.

Comment: For each thing in the array, look at the `classList` [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and check if that array includes 'c-block'

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:-

```
<script>
var array = ["i.fi.fi-bubble", "button.c-block", "div", "body.u-help", "html", "document", "Window"];
var index = array.filter(value => /c-block/.test(value));
console.log(index.length);
</script>
```